# Check if a row exists inside a MySQL function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In my `user` table the IDs `user_id` are randomly generated by the following functions:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE FUNCTION GenerateRandomUserID()
    RETURNS CHAR(15)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE user_id CHAR(15) DEFAULT '';

        WHILE LENGTH(user_id) < 15 DO
            SET user_id = CONCAT(user_id, SUBSTRING('0123456789', RAND() * 10 + 1, 1));
        END WHILE;

        RETURN user_id;
    END#
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER #
CREATE FUNCTION GenerateUniqueUserID()
    RETURNS CHAR(15)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE user_id CHAR(15) DEFAULT '';

        REPEAT
            SET user_id = GenerateRandomUserID();
        UNTIL NOT UserIDExists(user_id) END REPEAT;

        RETURN user_id;
    END#
DELIMITER ;
```

I then insert a user generating its ID with this function. So far so good. The problem is when I insert another user, which generates an infinite loop. I managed to boil down the problem to yet another function, `UserIDExists`, which always returns `TRUE` (it shouldn't, obviously).

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE FUNCTION UserIDExists(user_id CHAR(15))
    RETURNS BOOL
    BEGIN
        RETURN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = user_id);
    END#
DELIMITER ;
```

This last function does not do what it's supposed to, but I can't figure out why. If a single user exists with *any* password this will return `TRUE`, only if there are no users does it return `FALSE`. Can anyone figure out why?

Update:

I also tried this. Same result:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE UserIDExists(IN user_id CHAR(15), OUT user_id_exists BOOL)
    BEGIN
        SET user_id_exists = 0;
        SELECT 1 INTO user_id_exists FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = user_id;
    END#
DELIMITER ;
```

Update:

Tried this as well:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE UserIDExists(IN user_id CHAR(15), OUT user_id_exists BOOL)
    BEGIN
        IF ((SELECT `user_id` FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = user_id) != NULL) THEN
            SET user_id_exists = TRUE;
        ELSE
            SET user_id_exists = FALSE;
        END IF;
    END#
DELIMITER ;
```

Update:

I tried a few variantes with the following:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE UserIDExists_2(IN user_id CHAR(15), OUT user_id_exists CHAR)
    BEGIN
        SELECT `user_id` FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = user_id;
    END#
DELIMITER ;
```

And came to the conclusion that this returns `1` when `user_id` is also `1` and returns nothing for *any* other value. This is pretty odd, because this is the only row I have on the table:

```
# user_id, first_name, last_name, pwd, is_confirmed
'252316605573186', 'André', 'Fratelli', NULL, '0'
```

This is getting on my nerves...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I though that the quotes where enough to distinguish the procedure's arguments from the table's columns, but I guess I was wrong.

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE UserIDExists(IN p_user_id CHAR(15), OUT p_user_id_exists BOOL)
    BEGIN
        SET p_user_id_exists = EXISTS(SELECT `user_id` FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = p_user_id);
    END#
DELIMITER ;
```